# Ajustar colunas na Table do Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, table

Estou usando o Tkinter no Python, e também usando o recurso Table.

No meu código tenho uma linha, conforme a seguir:

table = Table (frame, dataframe=frame_entrada[['id', 'nome', 'usando_limite', 'telefone']], width = (largura - 100), height = (altura - 50), showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)

No entanto, quando executo o código, algumas colunas da tabela que aparecem no visor do computador não mostram os textos completos, como por exemplo, a coluna  'nome' corta os nomes completos de alguns clientes(dá pra ver apenas o início dos nomes, não o nome completo0. Como faço para ajustar automaticamente (ou até manualmente) a largura das colunas ao conteúdo das células?

Answer (score 0):

Você está posicionado o elemento Table em um frame, você tem que ver como você esta posicionando esse Frame, você esta usando o método .grid() ou .pack(), com grid você tem que especificar a posição dos elementos como se estivessem em uma tabella ( row e column) no entanto pack simplemente coloca o elemento em uma nova riga do root
Espero ter sido claro

Comment: Só preciso ajustar a largura da coluna à largura do conteúdo das células da planilha, ainda não consegui fazer, nem achei nada sobre.

Comment: @Ricardo você consegue editar a pergunta mostrando o codigo completo?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, estou o grid. A tabela tá exibindo normalmente na tela, com todos os campos corretamente. Só preciso ajustar a largura de algumas colunas que estão 'cortando' os dados exibidos, como a coluna 'nome'. Só quero ajustar a coluna ao conteúdo da célula...